# Filter Value on first sheet (user interface) to match filtered value on second sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I am attempting to make a interface dashboard - some screenshots below. The concept is to link the filtered value from a dragdown list on the main page to link to the same filtered value in one column on the second page. I cant seem to get it to work with the various variables ..

Here's some screenshots and my current VBA code. What am I doing wrong here ? Or is there an alternative to this ?

[image]

[image]

Code:

```
Range("T8:V8").Select
Sheets(" Detail (Internal)").Select
ActiveSheet.Range("$A:$CT").AutoFilter Field:=16, Criteria1:=Range("T8").Value
```

Appreciate everyone's help ..

Answer (score 0):

Selections gives nothing to you. Selection and ActiveSheet usage is not safe.

You must define variables

```
Dim sheet1 As Worksheet, sheet2 As Worksheet
Dim range1 As Range, range2 As Range
```

and then obtain and use references to sheets and ranges. Like:

```
Set sheet1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set range1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("T8")
sheet1.Range("$A:$CT").AutoFilter Field:=16, Criteria1:=range1.Value
```

or

```
Set range1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("$A:$CT")
Set range2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("T8")
range1.AutoFilter Field:=16, Criteria1:=range2.Value
```

or

```
Set sheet1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set sheet2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
sheet1.Range("$A:$CT").AutoFilter Field:=16, Criteria1:=sheet2.Range("T8").Value
```

and so on...

Comment: Nice catch on the `Range("T8")` without a defined parent worksheet but I wouldn't advice using default worksheet codenames as the names of variables.

Comment: Thanks Akina! This works perfectly now. I'm very new to VBA and was hence trying to edit through a recorded macro only. Realize now that not defining variables is my mistake. :)